# Redirecting to the other page after submitting radio button option

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I have a problem with my form. I need it to redirect user to different pages basing on which radio button was selected. User has to choose one of two options and click next, and according to his choice, page should redirect him to other page.

Here is the code as it looks for now

```
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Select option</legend>

        <center>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Osoba fizyczna"/>Non-company
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Firma"/>Company
        </br>
        <input type = "submit", class = "buttonStyle2", value=""/>
        </form>
        </center>
    </fieldset>
```

and then php code

```
 if(isset($_POST['Company'])

header("Location: http://myaddress.com/company.php");
```

Big thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['radio1']) && ($_POST['radio1']) == "Osoba fizyczna"){ // redirect }` but name both radio buttons the same name `name="radio1"` and change the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select option</legend>
    <center>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Osoba fizyczna"/>Non-company
    </br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Firma"/>Company
    </br>
    <input type = "submit" class = "buttonStyle2" value=""/>
    </form>
    </center>
</fieldset>
```

and

```
if ( isset($_POST['radio1']) ) {
    $filename = $_POST['radio1'] . "php";
    header("Location: http://myaddress.com/".$filename); 
}
```

Might be even better to set up an array with allowed values and check if radio1 is in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this.

***Sidenote:*** Make sure you're not outputting before header. [**Consult this page on Stack**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/) about possible `Headers already sent...`, should this occur and making sure [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set/on.

Otherwise, PHP will fail silently.

---

```
if(isset($_POST['radio1']) && ($_POST['radio1']) == "Osoba fizyczna"){

    header("Location: http://www.example.com/non_company.php"); 

 }

elseif(isset($_POST['radio1']) && ($_POST['radio1']) == "Firma"){

    header("Location: http://www.example.com/company.php"); 

 }

 else{
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/redirect_to_home.php"); 
}
```

**Nota:** The `else` would be if the person did not make a choice and simply clicked on submit without making a selection.

while using radio buttons of the same group name in your form:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Osoba fizyczna"/>Non-company
</br>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Firma"/>Company
```

---

Note about

```
<input type = "submit", class = "buttonStyle2", value=""/>
```

remove the commas

```
<input type = "submit" class = "buttonStyle2" value=""/>
```

Since HTML source in FF will reveal `No space between attributes` in red/as an error.